# Inconsistent implementation of std::setprecision() across C++ compilers

Tags: c++, precision

Suppose we have a variable of type double `GPA = 4.0`. According to the C++ standard, `setprecision(1)` should print the variable's value as `4.0` which is the number of digits printed after the decimal point.

Some compilers choose to print `4.` instead, seeming to specify the total number of digits instead of the number of digits after the decimal point. To achieve the same effect on these compilers, we must call `setprecision(2)` to print the value as `4.0`

Why are these compilers not conforming to C++ standards ? Namely, MinGW and GCC version 4.8.5

Comment: *"According to the C++ standard"* - where in the Standard did you read that?

Comment: According to both [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/), the behavior of `setprecision(1)` is correct.  Nowhere in those documents does it say "how many digits are generated *after the decimal*", they just says "how many digits are generated", and the code examples provided back up that behavior.

Comment: Perhaps you're getting confused with the behaviour when `std::fixed` is also specified....

Comment: In fact, [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) even states: "*Using the **default** floating-point notation, the precision field specifies the maximum number of meaningful digits to display **in total counting both those before and those after the decimal point**... In both the `fixed` and `scientific` notations, the precision field specifies exactly **how many digits to display after the decimal point**, even if this includes trailing decimal zeros. The digits before the decimal point are not relevant for the precision in this case.*".

Comment: So, for what you are attempting, you need to enable `fixed` so `setprecision(1)` will work as you expect.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did not know that `fixed` wasn't the default format. I understand now.